# PHP Generate Random 128-bit for persistent login

Tags: php, random, authentication

I'm making a persistent login using [this](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) setup.

How I understood it is that I need a extra table with username and a hash of the cookie token. Then you can have multiple tokens for one user.

The issue I'm having is that I need a random token. In the article they advise it to be 128 bits, so 16 hexadecimal values I guess. But these need to be truly random, because this is very important. To store them, I'll `bcrypt()` them, so that if the db is compromised it still takes 'long' before the cookies can be used to login to another account.

**TL;DR:** Need a true random 128-bit string/number/... . I've found several methods, but I don't know which ones are truly random.

Comment: and what is your measure of true randomness?

Comment: Of course since it's done by a server it's never truly random, but as random as can get...

Comment: well implemented pseudo random generator is random for practical purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel (especially with cryptography, you'll make it worse 99% of the time).
Try something like the [OpenSSL implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).

Comment: So `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` should be pretty random? Does it still need to be transformed to a hex or is it alrady a hex?

Comment: It'll return binary, you'll need to convert it to hex with `pack` or `bin2hex`.  As far as randomness, if it's cryptographically secure, it's about as good as it gets.